# Elegant way to open files from same folder but with different names

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a few files from the same folder but with different file names.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
agency = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\agency.txt')   
calendar = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\calendar.txt')   
fare_attributes = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\fare_attributes.txt')   
fare_rules = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\fare_rules.txt')   
routes = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\routes.txt')   
shapes = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\shapes.txt')   
stop_times = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\stop_times.txt')   
stops = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\stops.txt')   
translations = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\translations.txt')   
trips = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\trips.txt')
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/11004559

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `dict` to store the dataframe, as the filename is the key.

```
data = dict()
file_list = ['agency', 'calendar', 'fare_attributes', 'fare_rules', 'routes', 'shapes', 'stop_times', 'stops', 'translations', 'trips']
for file in file_list
    data[file] = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rafin\Desktop\work\Rafi\gtfs\files\%s.txt' % file)
```